# PHP Improve this function to delete a folder and all its contentadd a case for empty folders

Tags: php

I found in php.net this function which I like very much becasue I understood it :D

But it has a BUG, at least once.

If there is an empty folder it fails!
Is there a trick to improve this function without changing it too much?

```
function rrmdir($dir) 
{

foreach(glob($dir . '/*' ) as $file) 
    {

        if( is_dir($file) )
            rrmdir($file);
        else

            unlink($file);
    }

rmdir($dir);
}
```

If there is an empty folder the error is: invalid argument passed to foreach. I think the problem is that if is found an empty folder glob give no array. So foreach fails.

The original error:[image: The original error]

With Philip G FUNCTION[image: With Philip G FUNCTION]

Error with TIM function[image: Erro with TIM function]

Comment: Define 'fails'.  I don't immediately see why that shouldn't work on empty directories, and without an explanation of the failure mode it is difficult to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: added more informations

Comment: if glob has an error it will return boolean false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: newtphp: Would this be a good alternative for avoiding the jump with continue? (as suggested by OP, modified by me)**

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    $temp = scandir($dir);

    if (is_array($temp)) {
        $temp = array_diff($temp,array(".",".."));
        foreach($temp as $file) {   
            if( is_dir($dir."/".$file) )
                rrmdir($dir."/".$file);
            else
                unlink($dir."/".$file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

The `array_diff` removes the values in the second array from the first.

---

**Original post:**
If `glob` has an error it will return boolean `false` instead of an array. Since `foreach` expects an array, it won't work. Try this instead:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    $temp= glob($dir . '/*' );
    if (is_array($temp))
        foreach($temp as $file) {
            if( is_dir($file) )
                rrmdir($file);
            else
                unlink($file);
        }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

**EDIT** to properly handle hidden files, use this:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    $temp = scandir($dir);
    if (is_array($temp))
        foreach($temp as $file) {
            if($file=="." || $file=="..")
                continue;
            else if( is_dir($dir."/".$file) )
                rrmdir($dir."/".$file);
            else
                unlink($dir."/".$file);
        }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Unlike `glob`, `scandir` doesn't return the entire path of the file, so the code is a little more complicated.

This won't necessarily fix everything. It could still fail for other reasons. For example if the user doesn't have write permissions.

Comment: It is not deleting everything in all of the folders. You probably have dot files

Comment: yes the problem were some hidden files. Thanks to you too TIM.

Comment: I will see if I can come up with a simple fix for that

Comment: @newtphp ok, I updated it to fix the hidden file issue. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOW THIS WORKS PERFECT EVEN WITH HIDDEN FILE GREAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTTT!!!!!!

Comment: @newtphp glad I could help, thanks for the enthusiasm. Keep in mind it still requires correct permissions on the files.

Comment: No problem for permission. When a user create an account in the register.php I create a folder for the user with 0777 permission so he operate only in this folder with full permission. Note that this is a university project where security isn't really needed if someone could argue about giving full permission with 0777.

Comment: I've proposed a little mod to avoid CONTINUE . Is it ok?

Comment: @newtphp I approved your edit and modified it a bit to make it better.

Comment: @newtphp I think you are right that it is better/clearer without a continue, so I moved it to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach expects to get an array if the folder is empty. no array will be return, hence the invalid argument.

try this:

```
function rrmdir($dir) 
{
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 

    if(is_array($files)){
        foreach($files as $file) 
        {

            if( is_dir($file) ){
                rrmdir($file);
            }
            else{
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }

   rmdir($dir);
}
```

**EDIT**
or you could try this: (will not work recursive though)

```
function rrmdir($dir) 
{
   array_map('unlink', glob($dir . '/*')); 
   rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: error in " rmdir($dir);" ,last instruction: directory not empty

Comment: what does $file return? is that a valid path? The error you're having indicates that you haven't successfully deleted all files in the directory!

Comment: In data there is a file ".htaccess": is this the problem? Your function works removing via FTP all those .htaccess files

Comment: you could also try to change glod($dir ... etc) => array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
  Since glob doesnot return hidden files, while scandir does!

Comment: yes .htaccess is a hidden file, glob() doesn't return hidden files. use scan dir instead!

Comment: thank you very much! I will not use scandir since in the "real life" I will not have hidden files! Thank you very much! For try I put it a damend folder that i had on the desktop with a lot of hidden files!

Comment: With array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); I got error. I returned to glob. It works. I don't mind hidden file .file. This is for educational purpose. It's enough :D

Comment: `scandir` only returns an array with the basename, not the entire path like `glob` does. I think the fix is obvious, but see my updated answer for details.